# Double click listener on IFile, IFolder, IProject Object in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

How I can add my own double click listeners on `IFile`, `IFolder` and `IProject` object.

Default double click listener on these objects are as follows:

`IFile` objects - Corresponding file will be opened in associated editor.

`IFolder` or `IProject` Objects - Tree node will toggled(Expanded or collapsed)

Is it possible to **override/block/stop** these action and **execute/run** my own **action/command**?

Comment: This will depend on the individual view (if it can be done at all), is this the Package or Projects view?

Comment: Not package view it may be Navigator or Project view.

Answer (score 1):

`Project Explorer` is based on the [Common Navigator](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fcnf.htm). The common navigator looks for an action with id `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.Open` which is used instead of the normal double click handling if it is registered. So you may be able to do something with that.

The `Navigator` view is based on old, deprecated, view code. I don't see any way to change its behavior.